# asp:ListView set SelectMethod with a method having parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, model-binding

I have a Listview controls like this

```
<asp:ListView ID="categoryList" ItemType="CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.FavoriteVO" DataKeyNames="FavoriteID" GroupItemCount="1" SelectMethod="GetCategories" runat="server">
                       .....
</asp:ListView>
```

and in the code behind I'm setting the SelectMethod property

```
categoryList.SelectMethod = "GetbyTime";
```

Now if I want to call a parameterized method

```
public List<FavoriteVO> GetbyTime(string message)
        {
           ...
        }
```

How do I have to modify and assign to  **categoryList.SelectMethod  =** section ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to be able to change the SelectMethod to whatever you want.  Because of this, I would remove `SelectMethod="GetCategories"` from the control declaration and set that in codebehind as well.  At least that's where I would start.

Then it will be up to you to set the categoryList.SelectMethod in the proper places in code.  e.g. you probably want `categoryList.SelectMethod = "GetCategories";` in `if (IsPostBack) {}` and then `categoryList.SelectMethod = "GetbyTime";` within some other event or method, like from a button click or whatnot.

Comment: that may be true , but my question was something else

Answer (score -1):

It is VITAL, I repeat VITAL to set EnableViewState="False" on the html declaration of your usercontrol, if you are hosting an asp:ListView inside an ascx control, inside an aspx control!
I wasted days of development time because of this.